# Shorewall blocking outbound traffic to one IP on a vpn tunnel

Tags: openvpn, shorewall

I'm trying to set up shorewall to block traffic to one particular IP address that is routed over an openvpn tunnel.

Naively I have the following shorewall rules in place

```
#Don't allow connection pickup from the net
Invalid(DROP)   net     all     tcp

# Openvpn
ACCEPT  net     $FW     udp 1194

# All out
ACCEPT  $FW     net     all
DROP all net:146.aaa.yyy.xx

#PING
ACCEPT  $FW     loc     icmp
#ACCEPT $FW     net     icmp
```

But I can still ftp to 146.aaa.yyy.xx.

This traffic is routed through a second client vpn connection to another server that has a connection to the 146.aaa network, net the inbound openvpn connection shown here.

So I assume the vpn routing for the client connection is happening before this rule gets to it (or is my order wrong with the accept outbound being first)?

Am I on the right track here or barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: the drop rule should come before the accept all. The firewall will only work if it is aware of the traffic.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I suspect its because the traffic is being routed through the vpn before it hits the firewall.